# Creating a Custom Hook to Detect Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a custom hook which would return me the browsers name of the user. It is my first attempt in creating a custom hook to detect the browser.
I am setting the state in the hook with the browsers name and returning the state value which i thought would reflect in the component where i am using the Hook. But it only returns the first letter of the text.

Can someone here know what am i doing wrong here.

Below is my Code to detect the browsers Name

useDetectBrowser()

```
import React from "react";

export default function useDetectBrowser() {
  var sBrowser, sUsrAg = navigator.userAgent;
  const [ browserName, setBrowserName ] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
      sBrowser = "Mozilla Firefox";
      // "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
    } else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("SamsungBrowser") > -1) {
      sBrowser = "Samsung Internet";
      // "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SAMSUNG SM-G955F Build/PPR1.180610.011) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/9.4 Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
    } else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Opera") > -1 || sUsrAg.indexOf("OPR") > -1) {
      sBrowser = "Opera";
      // "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 OPR/57.0.3098.106"
    } else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Trident") > -1) {
      sBrowser = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
      // "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Zoom 3.6.0; wbx 1.0.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
    } else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Edge") > -1) {
      sBrowser = "Microsoft Edge";
      // "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 Edge/16.16299"
    } else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Chrome") > -1) {
      sBrowser = "Google Chrome or Chromium";
      // "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/66.0.3359.181 Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36"
    } else if (sUsrAg.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
      sBrowser = "Apple Safari";
      // "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1 980x1306"
    } else {
      sBrowser = "unknown";
    }
    setBrowserName(sBrowser);
  }, []);
  return browserName
}
```

// Usage:

```
const [ browserName, setBrowserName ] = useDetectBrowser();
  console.log(browserName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hook looks ok. The only error is usage of hook - return type is string, so currently you have assignment similar to:

```
const [ browserName /* "C" */, setBrowserName /* "h" */ ] = 'Chrome';
```

extracting first letter, to fix just change to

```
const browserName = useDetectBrowser();
```

Comment: Thanks! It happened so that i didnt check the setBrowserName!